# onclick="call_locker();" & Got error: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document':

Tags: javascript, php, css

My code:

```
<?php
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if(!IS_AJAX) {die("<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; background: #212833; left: 0; top: 0;'><div style='width: 70%; margin: 150px auto 0 auto; background: #fff; text-align:center; padding: 80px 100px; border-radius: 20px; font-family: Verdana; box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);'><h3 style='color: #000; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0;'>Huh.. wait a second!</h3><h1 style='margin: 5px 0 0 0; color: #fc4349; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px;'>Nosey little mouse, aren't you?</h1><p style='font-size: 1em; color: #555;'>There is nothing interesting here, no point waisting your time.</p></div></div>");}
?>
<div class="property-hv">
    <h2>Almost Done<span class="ellipsis-anim"><span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></span></h2>
    <div class="property-hv-i animated bounceIn">
        <h3 class="hv-ls-t">Success!<span class="property-hv-overview-v"></span></h3>
        <p class="hv-ls-n-1">       
            Thank you
        </p>
        <p class="hv-ls-n-2">       
            next step.
        </p>
        <div class="verification-button-w">
            <a class="verification-button" href="https://google.com/offer"><span>Confirm</span></a>
        </div>
        <p class="hv-ls-n-3">
            Please proceed to enter your information
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to implement "Content locker" example: https://www.cpagrip.com/view.php?id=1609935

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WIZd.png)

I've added to main.js:

```
var flBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("verification-button");

[].slice.call(flBtns).forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
    // call your locker function here.
    call_locker()
  })
})
```

and changed the index.php to below code:

```
<?php
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if(!IS_AJAX) {die("<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; background: #212833; left: 0; top: 0;'><div style='width: 70%; margin: 150px auto 0 auto; background: #fff; text-align:center; padding: 80px 100px; border-radius: 20px; font-family: Verdana; box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);'><h3 style='color: #000; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0;'>Huh.. wait a second!</h3><h1 style='margin: 5px 0 0 0; color: #fc4349; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px;'>Nosey little mouse, aren't you?</h1><p style='font-size: 1em; color: #555;'>There is nothing interesting here, no point waisting your time.</p></div></div>");}
?>
<div class="property-hv">
    <h2>Almost Done<span class="ellipsis-anim"><span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></span></h2>
    <div class="property-hv-i animated bounceIn">
        <h3 class="hv-ls-t">Success! <span class="property-hv-overview-v"></span></h3>
        <p class="hv-ls-n-1">       
            Thank you
        </p>
        <p class="hv-ls-n-2">       
            next step.
        </p>
        <div class="verification-button-w">
            <a href="#" class="fl-button">FL Button 1</a>
        </div>
        <p class="hv-ls-n-3">
            Please proceed to enter your information
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="https://superfolder.net/script_include.php?id=1609935"></head>
```

Now, am not getting any content locker. plus am getting error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0s3M.png)

How to implement the content locker in accurate way & where am falling.

Thank you.
regards.